# Why are trigonometric substitutions valid?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Within an integral, when you make a trigonometric substitution like $x = \sin(\theta)$ for $x$, aren't you changing the possible range of values for $x$? Aren't you limiting the possible values of $x$ from those between $-1$ and $1$ when you make the substitution? Thus, why is the substitution mathematically valid?

Comment: If our integral involves $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, as it so often does, there is already a restriction to $|x|\le |a|$.

Comment: ...and at times we do use tan so as to avoid that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...which is why you can't make a substitution like that for a bigger range. Instead, you have to make the substitution $x = a \sin \theta$ so that the possible range of values is not changed.